# Donde poner la clave foránea

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo maquetado un modelo **entidad relación** con sus correspondientes cardinalidades, a la hora de escribir las tablas para migrarlas en laravel me viene la siguiente duda a la cabeza, ¿en qué tabla coloco la foreign key, en la que tengo **1:1** o la que tengo de **0:N**?..

**EDIT: el enunciado es el siguiente, las reparaciones tienen un cliente, y un cliente puede tener varias reparaciones (o no tener ninguna).**

Expongo a continuación dos imágenes de ejemplo con cada uno de los casos:

**Clave foránea en tabla de "reparaciones"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Clave foránea en tabla de "clientes"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería una buena explicación para saberlo la próxima vez que se me presente la situación.. gracias!

Comment: 1 cliente tiene N(muchas) reparaciones. La foránea debe ir en reparaciones.

Comment: apoyo el comentario de @BrandonCastillo aunque también te comento que la respuesta debe salir del enunciado que tratas de resolver, además que este es un tema enteramente de bases de datos no de Laravel

Comment: en cuanto a modelamiento de datos es dificil decir incluso si es 1 a N porque puede ser N a N , con tu reputacion que tienes , puedes entrar al [chat] y cualquiera de los que esten te ayudaran mejor

Comment: He editado la pregunta para poner el enunciado @AlfredoPaz, gracias por las respuestas, os estoy leyendo y a la vez dando cabezazos en la mesa jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el enunciado que mencionaste, al ser una **relacion de muchos a uno**, la clave foranea *(en buenas practicas)* siempre viaja a la tabla de '**muchos'**.

Entonces para tu ejercio, la clave foranea esta en la tabla *Reparaciones*.

Para mas informacion sobre [relaciones](https://baseser.blogspot.com/2010/07/tipos-de-relaciones.html) y [buenas practicas](https://videlcloud.wordpress.com/2017/03/05/buenas-practicas-para-el-diseno-de-base-de-datos/), consulta los enlaces.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Con tabla _"Reportes"_ supongo que te refieres a _"Reparaciones"_, si es así creo que se me está esclareciendo la duda, por cierto, buenos enlaces los que has dejado. Si no veo una respuesta mejor desarrollada te la doy como correcta.

Comment: Tienes razon, era Raparaciones, me confundi, ya edito mi respuesta, por cualquier duda avisame que agrego mas contenido, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Clave foránea en tabla de "reparaciones"

ya que las en la tabla reparaciones se requiere relacionarlo al cliente que pertenece dicha reparación.

y ademas se puede tener registros de varias reparaciones que ha solicitado el mismo cliente

espero haberme explicado.

Comment: entiendo lo que dices, el problema está cuando tengo que maquetarlo, me cuesta entender para donde pongo la flecha que corresponda o las cardinalidades.. sería algo así pues ? https://imgur.com/a/3aJCAFx Gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

La clave foránea debe de estar en la tabla "reparaciones".

En cuestión la idea de las claves foráneas es eliminar la redundancia de datos que se presentan en la Base de Datos, es por esto que pasa a ser un numero en donde se repite reiteradas veces, en este caso el nombre del cliente dentro de la tabla "reparaciones" ya que las reparaciones pertenecen al clientes.

Yo siempre cuando hago una tabla me hago la siguiente pregunta, llevándolo al cazo seria; ¿Cuantos clientes puede tener una reparación? o ¿Cuantas reparaciones puede tiene el cliente? y me respondo:

- Las reparaciones solo pertenecen a un cliente por lo tanto tengo que asignarles la ID del cliente a quien le hice la reparación
- A los los clientes les puedo realizar varias reparaciones por lo tanto seria inconsistente asignarle una ID de la tabla "reparaciones" a la tabla "clientes", esto generaría varios clientes donde solo un campo variaría.

Espero haber resuelto tus dudas.